# Target child with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="topLevel">
    <span class="misc pointDown"></span>
<span class="misc"></span>
<span class="b">item</span>
</div>
```

When I click on the topLevel I need to replace "pointDown" with "pointUp". I think I have difficulty targeting the right element.

```
$(".topLevel").live('click', function() {
    $(this).next("span").removeClass("pointDown").addClass("pointUp");
});
```

Comment: If this has to work both ways, instead of all the .addClass .removeClass in the answers below you might like to use .toggleClass('pointDown').toggleClass('pointUp')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".topLevel").live('click', function() {
    $(this).children('.misc').first()
           .removeClass("pointDown").addClass("pointUp");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".topLevel").live('click', function() {
   $(this).find("span:eq(0)").removeClass("pointDown").addClass("pointUp");
});
```

Comment: @Neal why does `:first-child` not work in all browsers? This is jQuery, not native selector support.

Comment: @Box9 - try it out and ull see ^_^

Comment: @Neal I don't have every browser to try it out on... any hints?

Comment: @Box9 -- [look here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild#compatibilitysection) :-D

Comment: Neal, as I mentioned earlier, jQuery support is different to native browser support as jQuery can emulate the behaviour. [This jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htErx/) works in IE6, even though IE6 has no support for `:first-child` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.topLevel').live('click', function() {
    $(this).children('span.pointDown').removeClass("pointDown").addClass("pointUp"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume the first item is your element - it's not the proper answer (if you ask me).

```
$('.topLevel').click(function() {
     $(this).find('.misc.pointDown').removeClass('pointDown').addClass('pointUp');
}
```